# Filter JSON by key value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

given an array of objects in users.json:

```
{"key":"userSubscriptions","value":
[{"channel":"Netflix","user":"Bobby","region":"NA"},
[{"channel":"Netflix","user":"Bobby","region":"EU"},
[{"channel":"Netflix","user":"Jamie","region":"SEA"},
[{"channel":"Prime Video","user":"Bobby","region":"NA"}]}
```

How would one filter such that the end result will be

```
console.log(result); // Bobby, your region subscriptions are: Netflix: (NA, EU), Prime Video: (NA)
```

Thank you!

EDIT: i tried using .filter() & .map() method but no luck so far

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: This is clearly invalid, you have 4 `[` and 1 `]`

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: It's a nightmare to filter JSON, convert it to a JS object, and filter that JS object instead.

Comment: @Teemu _"It's a nightmare to filter JSON"_ - How do you filter a string? o.O

Comment: @Andreas That's the point of my comment.

Comment: Tried using .filter() & .map() method but no luck so far

Answer (score 0):

you have to use lodash to group data, then map data

```
var data = {
                "key":"userSubscriptions",
                "value":
                [{"channel":"Netflix","user":"Bobby","region":"NA"},
                {"channel":"Netflix","user":"Bobby","region":"EU"},
                {"channel":"Netflix","user":"Jamie","region":"SEA"},
                {"channel":"Prime Video","user":"Bobby","region":"NA"}]
            }

            var users = _.chain(data.value)
                .groupBy("user").map((value, key) => ({ user: key, data: value })).value();

                users.forEach(element => {
                    console.log(element)

                    console.log(`${element.user}, your region subscriptions are: Netflix: ${element.data.map(c=>c.channel).join(',')}, Prime Video: ${element.data.map(c=>c.region).join(',')}`)
                });
```

Comment: _"you have to use lodash to group data"_ - No, OP has not to use a library just for that purpose. That's easily done with the native objects and methods.

Comment: because the question is not clear, so i think he want to print out for all users

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data is invalid. However, I think I adapted it to what you intended.

This breaks the data down into a by-user format, and supplies a function to output the Subscriptions and Regions for any named user.

```js
const jsonString = `{"key":"userSubscriptions","value":[{"channel":"Netflix","user":"Bobby","region":"NA"},{"channel":"Netflix","user":"Bobby","region":"EU"},{"channel":"Netflix","user":"Jamie","region":"SEA"},{"channel":"Prime Video","user":"Bobby","region":"NA"}]}`;

const obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);                                  // parse the data from a string into an object

const byUser = obj.value.reduce((acc, o) => {                        // reduce the "value" array to a single object
  if (!acc[o.user]) acc[o.user] = {};                                // create acc.userName if it does not exist
  if (acc[o.user][o.channel]) acc[o.user][o.channel].push(o.region); // if acc.userName.channelName has an array, add this region to it
  else acc[o.user][o.channel] = [o.region];                          // else create an array with this region in it
  return acc;                                                        // keep the created object for the next iteration
}, {});

function printForUser(userName) {                                    // create a function that takes a user's name
  const user = byUser[userName];                                     // take the user object from the byUser object
  return Object.keys(user).reduce((acc, k) => {                      // reduce the keys of the user object to one string
    return acc + ` ${k}: (${user[k].join(", ")}),`;                  // add on each subscription and regions
  }, `${userName}, your region subscriptions are:`).slice(0, -1);    // initialize the string and remove the last comma
}

console.log( printForUser("Bobby") );
```